# Instruments showing leak even when reference count is 0

Tags: ios, instruments

I ran the Leaks instrument on my project. The instrument is showing a certain object to be leaked, even when its reference count is getting shown as 0.

[image]

Is it a false leak? Or am I missing something?

**EDIT:**
I can't share the code here as it is proprietary. I can only explain the scenario and hope it makes sense. I have a class which spawns a separate thread in one of its methods. Before that, a strong mutable array property (say pArray) is allocated with [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] and self is added to it.

```
self.pArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self.pArray addObject:self];
```

The pArray property is released after the secondary thread has finished its tasks. When pArray is allocated thus, Leaks instrument showed a leak at the allocation line. Also, leaks were shown at the place where this class' object was instantiated. However, when I allocated pArray like this,

```
NSMutableArray *pTempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.pArray = pTempArray;
pTempArray = nil;
```

the leak went away. However, the leak for the class still shows, but the reference count of the class is 0 as I have mentioned in the image.

Comment: This cannot be answered without seeing the code.

Comment: can't share the code as that is company property. I shall try to explain the scenario in an edit.

Comment: Reproduce the error in a test project then.

Comment: I tried doing that, but sadly the leak did not reproduce in the test project

Comment: so the leak stems from the code you can't show and thus it is rather hard to help. make sure you don't have any circular references... they tend to produce that